# Cannot run Python Subprocess calls using Jenkins

Tags: python, jenkins, subprocess

The question has been asked elsewhere, but I do not see any solutions for this...

I have a Python script that contains subprocess calls of the form:

```
source_density = subprocess.check_output(["adb", device_dhm1, "-P8080", "-s", source, "shell", "wm density | head -2 | tail -1"])
```

When running this script through cmd, everything runs fine. However now I am trying to run it through Jenkins and I am getting the following error output:

```
======================================================================
ERROR: test_sanity (__main__.ABC)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user123/.jenkins/workspace/Test/Jenkins-Source-Sanity.py", line 145, in test_sanity
    source_density = subprocess.check_output(["adb", device_dhm1, "-P8080", "-s", source, "shell", "wm density | head -2 | tail -1"])
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 216, in check_output
    process = Popen(stdout=PIPE, *popenargs, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 394, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1047, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Comment: The error message suggests your program cannot locate the executable file `adb`. You can check the `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: but I am wondering why I don't see this when running via terminal?

Comment: Looks like it cannot find adb command in PATH, maybe you can try giving full path like `/usr/bin/adb`

Comment: You have to set `shell=True` in the call of check_output

Comment: @RishabhArya Thank you! giving the full path to adb worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

Per default, `check_output` treats the first argument as a single executable instead of a shell command (cmd command). So you have to set the flag `shell=True` explicitly.

```
source_density = subprocess.check_output(["adb", device_dhm1, "-P8080", "-s", source, "shell", "wm density | head -2 | tail -1"], shell=True)
```

Please read the doc [here](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output).